# React Native Shadow is not similar for the same code

Tags: react-native

So i have made some buttons and given them shadows, the button is  a component with different color but same shadow,but the shadow is not same in the output

**The View**

```
<View style={styles.top}>
        <FlatButton text={"LOGIN"} color={"#F0DBAF"}/>
        <FlatButton text={"LOGIN"} color={"#29ADB2"}/>
        <FlatButton text={"LOGIN"} color={"#C5E898"}/>
        <FlatButton text={"Admin"} color={"#F0DBAF"}/>
      </View>
```

**Its Css**

```
top: {
    flex: 5,
    justifyContent:'space-evenly',
    alignItems:'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
```

**Button component**

```
import {StyleSheet, Text, TouchableNativeFeedback, View} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

const FlatButton = ({text, onPress, color}) => {
  return (
    <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={onPress}>
      <View style={{...styles.button, backgroundColor: color}}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableNativeFeedback>
  );
};

export default FlatButton;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    width: '100%',
    paddingVertical: 14,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 5,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.36,
    shadowRadius: 6.68,
    elevation: 11,
  },
  text: {
    color: 'white',
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-SemiBold',
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

[Screenshot of Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5k7A.png)

to fix the problem with shadow